# Respond.min.js and IE

Tags: jquery

I'm testing respond.min.js and conflicts. There is an issue with
IE8 throwing error like:
  'undefined' is null or not an object  respond.min.js, line 6 character 845

I'm using Respond.js v1.1.0.
Error is the following:

```
{var d=a.match(/@media[^\{]+\{([^\{\}]*\{[^\}\{]*\})+/gi)
```

Why is this actually?

Comment: Try to re-download the latest version of respond.js, or use the non-minified version to see the *real* error.

Comment: What version of respond.min.js are you using? This doesn't match anything in the latest Respond.js version from https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Comment: The version you're using was only the third version released is over two years out of date. If you're experiencing an issue and you don't think it's with your code, you might want to try using a more up to date version in which many issues have likely been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Respond.js version 1.1.0 is over two years out of date. The current version is 1.4.2, and in the release notes for 1.4.1 it says:

> Fixing a potential parsing issue in IE8

I can't confirm whether that's the specific parsing issue you're experiencing without the rest of your code, but updating to the current version of the library will rid you of any known and fixed errors, which as per that changelog, it sounds like yours may be.